# how could i use an if statement to represent this scenario?

Tags: r

generate independent RandomVariables XM ∼ Unif(−25,25) and YM ∼ Unif(−25,25), then if X^2M + Y^ 2 M ≤ 25^2 take ( XM,YM) as the outcome, but if X^2 M +Y ^2 M > 25^2 try again — and keep trying until you have accepted an outcome. my question is how would I consider the X^2 M +Y ^2 M > 25^2 bit in an if statement.here's my attempt

```
XM=runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
YM=runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
if(XM^2+Ym^2<=25^2)
{
(XM,YM)
}else
{
(XM,YM)


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `repeat` like below

```
res <- c()
repeat {
  XM <- runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
  YM <- runif(1,min=-25,max=25)
  if (XM**2+YM**2<=25**2) {
    res <- rbind(res,data.frame(XM,YM))
    break
  } else {
    res <- rbind(res,data.frame(XM,YM))
  }
}
```